# How to pass data to another domain while redirection from one domain to another domain

Tags: javascript

I am loggedin on a website and on the click of button I am redirecting to another website . I want to be loggedin with the same credentials I have used in the previous website.

I have tried cookie , but it's only for the same domain .

Lastly I have tried -

```
let url = domain-name + '?data='+some-data;
window.open(url);
```

So what is the best way to pass data to another website?

Comment: Both websites are owned by you? If not: How do you log into that other site? Does that other site allow users to log in via third parties?

Comment: Yes , Both website are owned by me  and same users will access both the website .

Comment: Here is how StackExchange does it: https://nickcraver.com/blog/2017/05/22/https-on-stack-overflow/#global-login